The word "чайный" as a substantive
In Детство Люверс by Boris Pasternak I read:

Ходили на блоках двери чайных

If I am not wrong, here "чайный" is a субстантивированное прилагательное. I could not find in any dictionary the use of "чайный" as a субстантивированное прилагательное with this meaning. What is the meaning exactly? Here is the context: we are in Ekaterinburg at the beginning of the 20th century (before 1917). Were "чайные" teahouses, that is establishments where one could drink (exclusively?) tea and eat pastries? Can we use this word nowadays with this meaning?

The word is чайная.
It does mean "a tea house", or, more precisely, "a tea room".
It, probably, can be treated as a substantivated adjective, but "ellipsis" (from чайная комната) would likely be a better term. Substantivated adjectives are usually formed from the neuter.
It's quite common for Russian to form the names of premises and establishments using an adjective in the feminine singular: гостиная "living room" (literally: "guest room"), столовая "cafeteria" or "dining room" (literally: "table room"), котельная "boiler room", пельменная "dumpling place", рюмочная "bar" (literally, "shot glass place") etc.
Some people get creative and name their establishments "Укулелешная", "Настоишная", "Балалаечная", "Рёберная", etc. Those are the eye spellings of "ukulele place", "bitters place", "balalaika place" and "rib place", accordingly. Those all are not real words, but the paradigm is widespread enough so that these names get the idea across.

Were "чайные" teahouses, that is establishments where one could drink (exclusively?) tea and eat pastries?

Tea was the only non-alcoholic stimulant widely available, so it was not that much about quality pastime with pastries and other fancy things, but more about a utilitarian place where people who worked outdoors could warm up and recharge a little bit. They didn't serve alcohol, but did serve simple hot snacks.

Can we use this word nowadays with this meaning?

Nowadays, it's almost exclusively means солдатская чайная: a store on a military base where they sell basic necessities like snacks, toothpaste, razors, needles, thread and so on. They don't usually actually serve tea in there.
